# asp.net InsertCommand to return latest insert ID

Tags: asp.net, sql-insert, tableadapter, scope-identity, typed-dataset

I'm unable to retrieve the latest inserted id from my SQL Server 2000 db using a typed dataset in asp.NET

I have created a tableadapter and I ticked the "Refresh datatable" and "Generate Insert, Update and Delete statements". This auto-generates the Fill and GetData methods, and the Insert, Update, Select and Delete statements.

I have tried every possible solution in this thread

http://forums.asp.net/t/990365.aspx

but I'm still unsuccesfull, it always returns 1(=number of affected rows). 
I do not want to create a seperate insert method as the auto-generated insertCommand perfectly suits my needs.

As suggested in the thread above, I have tried to update the InsertCommand SQL syntax to add SELECT SCOPY_IDENTITY() or something similar, I have tried to add a parameter of type ReturnValue, but all I get is the number of affected rows.

Does anyone has a different take on this?
Thanks in advance!
Stijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully found a way to get the incremental id after insert using my table adapter.

My approach is a little different, I'm using a Store procedure to make the insert, so my insert command has all the values but the ID, I made the sp return the ID just calling:
 SET @ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
and then 
 COMMIT TRAN 
and last line will be 
 RETURN @ID

Then I searched my table adapter parameters for InsertCommand and set the @RETURNVALUE to the column of the incremental ID of the table, so when it's executed automatically put the return value on the id field.

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I decided to give up, I can't afford to waste any more time on this.
I use the Insert statement after which I do a select MAX(id) query to hget the insert ID

If anyone should have a solution, I'll be glad to read it here

Thanks
Stijn

Comment: What if you use seperate insert query instead of autogenerated?

Comment: using Max(id) is bad approach, if many user entering data, Wrong ID will be returned...

Answer (score 0):

> **You need to tell your table's table-adapter to refresh the
>   data-table after update/insert operation.
>   This is how you can do that.**

1. Open the properties of **TableAdapter -> Default Select Query -> Advnaced options**. and Check the option of **Refresh the data table**. Save the adapter now. Now when you call update on table-adapter, the **data-table will be updated [refreshed] after the update/insert operation** and will reflect the latest values from database table. **if the primary-key or any coloumn is set to auto-increment, the data-table will have those latest value post recent update.**
2. Now you can Call the update as TableAdapterObj.Update(ds.dataTable);
3. **Read latest values from the DataTable(ds.dataTable) coloumns and assign respective values into the child table before update/insert**. This will work exactly the way you want.

[alt text http://ruchitsurati.net/files/tds1.png](http://ruchitsurati.net/files/tds1.png)